# Kafka DefaultPartitioner could not be found error?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am trying to create a simple kafka consumer and producer in order to reach them from another application running on Cytoscape which is a data visualization software. So I did a simple app to just send and receive a message, producer produces a message and consumer prints it as an information message. Here is the classes I used:

Consumer:

```
public Consumer(String topicName, String groupID, CySwingAppAdapter adapter){
    this.topicName = topicName;
    this.groupID = groupID;
    this.consumerThread = new ConsumerThread(topicName,groupID,adapter);
    this.adapter = adapter;
}

public void startKafka(){
    ConsumerThread consumerThread = new ConsumerThread(topicName, groupID, adapter);
    consumerThread.start();
}

public void stopKafka() {
    try {
        consumerThread.getKafkaConsumer().wakeup();
        consumerThread.join();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private static class ConsumerThread extends Thread {

    private String topicName;
    private String groupID;
    private KafkaConsumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer;
    private CySwingAppAdapter adapter;

    public ConsumerThread(String topicName, String groupID, CySwingAppAdapter adapter) {
        this.topicName = topicName;
        this.groupID = groupID;
        this.adapter = adapter;
    }

    public void run() {
        Properties configProperties = new Properties();
        configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:32768");
        configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupID);

        kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(configProperties);
        kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topicName), new ConsumerRebalanceListener() {
            public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
                System.out.println("Information: This consumer does not listen" +
                        Arrays.toString(partitions.toArray()) + " partition anymore.");
            }
            public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
                System.out.println("Information: This consumer is now listening: " + Arrays.toString(partitions.toArray())
                        + " partition(s)");
            }
        });

        try {
            while (true) {
                ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(100);
                for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(adapter.getCySwingApplication().getJFrame(),record.value(),
                            "Information!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (WakeupException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        kafkaConsumer.close();
    }

    public KafkaConsumer<String, String> getKafkaConsumer() {
        return this.kafkaConsumer;
    }
}
```

Producer Class:

```
public Producer(String topicName, String input, CySwingAppAdapter adapter){
    this.adapter = adapter;
    this.topicName = topicName;
    this.input = input;

    this.configProperties = new Properties();
    configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"localhost:32768");
    configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.PARTITIONER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaPartitioner.class.getCanonicalName());
    configProperties.put("Partition0","a");
    configProperties.put("Partition1","b");
    this.producer = new KafkaProducer(configProperties);
}

public void produceSmth(){
    ProducerRecord<String, String> rec = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topicName, input);
    producer.send(rec, new Callback() {
        public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception exception) {
            System.out.println("Sended record metadata:\nMessage: " + input + "\nTopic: " +
                    metadata.topic() + "\nPartition: " + metadata.partition());
        }

    });

}

public void stopProducer(){
    producer.close();
}
```

Partitioner Class:

```
public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs) {
    for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry: configs.entrySet()){
        if(entry.getKey().startsWith("Partition")){
            key = entry.getKey();
            value = (String)entry.getValue();
            int paritionId = Integer.parseInt(key.substring(9));
            kafkaPartitioner.put(value,paritionId);
        }
    }
}

public int partition(String topic, Object key, byte[] keyBytes, Object value, byte[] valueBytes,
                     Cluster cluster) {
    partitionList = cluster.availablePartitionsForTopic(topic);
    input = (String)value;
    prefix = ((String) value).split("-")[0];
    if(kafkaPartitioner.containsKey(prefix)){
        return kafkaPartitioner.get(prefix);
    }else {
        int noOfPartitions = cluster.topics().size();
        return  value.hashCode()%noOfPartitions + kafkaPartitioner.size() ;
    }
}
```

The class that I reach the Items above:

```
this.consumer = new Consumer("demo", "group1", adapter);
this.producer = new Producer("demo", "a-hello world", adapter);
consumer.startKafka();
producer.produceSmth();
producer.stopProducer();
consumer.stopKafka();
```

When I run the code, It gives `DefaultPartitioner could not be found` error. The whole error message is below. Where am I doing wrong?

Error Message:

```
> org.cytoscape.app.internal.exception.AppStartupException: App constructor threw exception
at org.cytoscape.app.internal.manager.SimpleApp.start(SimpleApp.java:187)
at org.cytoscape.app.internal.manager.AppManager$1.onFileCreate(AppManager.java:502)
at org.apache.commons.io.monitor.FileAlterationObserver.doCreate(FileAlterationObserver.java:379)
at org.apache.commons.io.monitor.FileAlterationObserver.checkAndNotify(FileAlterationObserver.java:345)
at org.apache.commons.io.monitor.FileAlterationObserver.checkAndNotify(FileAlterationObserver.java:304)
at org.apache.commons.io.monitor.FileAlterationMonitor.run(FileAlterationMonitor.java:182)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.cytoscape.app.internal.manager.SimpleApp.start(SimpleApp.java:175)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:181)
at Action.Producer.<init>(Producer.java:30)
at App.MyControlPanel.<init>(MyControlPanel.java:130)
at App.CytoVisProject.<init>(CytoVisProject.java:29)
... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner for configuration partitioner.class: Class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner could not be found.
at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseType(ConfigDef.java:255)
at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.define(ConfigDef.java:78)
at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.define(ConfigDef.java:94)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.<clinit>(ProducerConfig.java:206)
... 15 more
org.cytoscape.app.internal.exception.AppStartupException: App constructor threw exception
at org.cytoscape.app.internal.manager.SimpleApp.start(SimpleApp.java:187)
at org.cytoscape.app.internal.manager.AppManager$1.onFileCreate(AppManager.java:502)
at org.apache.commons.io.monitor.FileAlterationObserver.doCreate(FileAlterationObserver.java:379)
at org.apache.commons.io.monitor.FileAlterationObserver.checkAndNotify(FileAlterationObserver.java:345)
at org.apache.commons.io.monitor.FileAlterationObserver.checkAndNotify(FileAlterationObserver.java:304)
at org.cytoscape.app.internal.manager.AppManager.checkForFileChanges(AppManager.java:781)
at org.cytoscape.app.internal.manager.AppManager.installApp(AppManager.java:870)
at org.cytoscape.app.internal.task.InstallAppsTask.run(InstallAppsTask.java:32)
at org.cytoscape.work.internal.task.JDialogTaskManager$TaskRunnable.innerRun(JDialogTaskManager.java:342)
at org.cytoscape.work.internal.task.JDialogTaskManager$TaskRunnable.run(JDialogTaskManager.java:355)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.cytoscape.app.internal.manager.SimpleApp.start(SimpleApp.java:175)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:181)
at Action.Producer.<init>(Producer.java:30)
at App.MyControlPanel.<init>(MyControlPanel.java:130)
at App.CytoVisProject.<init>(CytoVisProject.java:29)
... 19 more
```

Comment: Are you using Maven, for example? If not, how are you adding libraries to the classpath?

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for the answer. Yes I am using Maven.